# Описание при нажатии на кнопку поделиться

Tags: html

Всем привет. Есть кнопки поделиться в соц сетях. Но вот затрудненность.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как подставить туда некое описание. Т.е. он берет title И подставляет его (продукция), а есть же еще поле описание? откуда он его берет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Специально для этих целей существует [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/)

С помощью него можно подставить и описание и превью и прочее подобное.

Конкретно за описание отвечает `og:description`